Firebase Test Lab auto grant permissions for UI tests
Is there any documentation stating FTL installs the app with the -g flag, meaning manifest permissions are automatically granted? I cannot find in my digging. Thanks!
I looked into firebase test lab documentation and cannot find any confirmation

Same. I want to prevent FTL from granting all the permissions to my app, as granting permissions is part of my UI tests.
